# I am confused with the kernel or filter

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I read an article, and the authors use a CNN with the following scheme :

```
-----------------

Input image 30*30 => Feature maps => Feature maps =>  Feature maps => Feature maps
                       28 * 28          14*14            12*12            6*6
-----------------
            Filtring 5*3*3   downsampling 2*2    Filtring 5*3*3   downsampling 2*2
```

With my comprehension we have two filter 5 * 3 and the last 3 correspond to the channel RGB so 3, is it correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it means you have 5 channels (means 5 filters/kernels) of 3x3.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

```
What they are trying to say is that:

First:
the conv is being done using 5 different 3x3 2d kernels
input 30x30 ==> output 5 different 28x28

Second:
max pool 2x2 ie the output dim becomes halved
input 28x28 ==> output 14x14

Third:
the conv is being done using 5 different 3x3 2d kernels
input 14x14 ==> output 5 different 12x12

Lastly:
max pool 2x2 ie the output dim becomes halved
input 12x12 ==> output 6x6
```